# Unable to use several find() functions using mongoose to pass in res.render

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm working on a website that shows several movies in different category groups on the home page, hence my attempt to use several find functions (mongoose) and pass them in a render to display them in a view together. The issue is if I try to store the movies array from the find function in a variable or res.locals, it just remains "undefined." I can't seem to figure out how to pass several of these arrays in one get response. I'm new to Node and any help is appreciated!

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // array of top-selling movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Top-Selling Movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      res.locals.topMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of new movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "New rental movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      res.locals.newMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of recommended movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Recommended For You"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      res.locals.recMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of action/thrilling movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Thrilling movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      res.locals.actionMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  res.render("categories");
});
```

I even tried:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var topMovies;
  var newMovies;
  var recMovies;
  var actionMovies;
  // array of top-selling movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Top-Selling Movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      topMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of new movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "New rental movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      newMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of recommended movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Recommended For You"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      recMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  // array of action/thrilling movies
  Movie.find({
    group: "Thrilling movies"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // In EJS, use found items array and tap into attributes to display in frontend
      actionMovies = movies;
    }
  });
  res.render("categories", {
    topMovies: topMovies,
    newMovies: newMovies,
    recMovies: recMovies,
    actionMovies: actionMovies
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async/await` for that

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const topMovies = await Movie.find({ group: "Top-Selling Movies" })
  const newMovies = await Movie.find({ group: "New rental movies" })
  const recMovies = await Movie.find({ group: "Recommended For You" })
  const actionMovies = await Movie.find({ group: "Thrilling movies" })


  return res.render("categories", {
    topMovies: topMovies,
    newMovies: newMovies,
    recMovies: recMovies,
    actionMovies: actionMovies
  });
});
```

or for a better looking code

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const [topMovies, newMovies, recMovies, actionMovies] = await Promise.all([
    Movie.find({ group: "Top-Selling Movies" }),
    Movie.find({ group: "New rental movies" }),
    Movie.find({ group: "Recommended For You" }),
    Movie.find({ group: "Thrilling movies" })
  ])


  return res.render("categories", {
    topMovies,
    newMovies,
    recMovies,
    actionMovies
  });
});
```

Edit: also in your example you can limit database queries by just using the filter method

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const movies = await Movie.find()

  const topMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.group === 'Top-Selling Movies');
  const newMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.group === 'New rental movies');
  const recMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.group === 'Recommended For You');
  const actionMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.group === 'Thrilling movies');

  return res.render("categories", {
    topMovies,
    newMovies,
    recMovies,
    actionMovies
  });
});
```